# google+ API moments object metadata

Tags: php, google-api

I want to post a moment to the user's google+ account.  I have an example working using a google page with schema.org markup.  This is the post body sent in the request:

```
{
  "type": "http://schema.org/AddAction",
  "object": {
    "url": "https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/examples/thing"
  }
}
```

The schema markup for this url looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>The Google+ Platform</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="thing.ico" />
  </head>
  <body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Thing">
    <section>Name: <div itemprop="name">The Google+ Platform</div></section>
    <section>Description: <div itemprop="description">Google+ is more than just
      plus.google.com. It's about adding people to all Google products. The
      Google+ platform extends this idea, allowing you to add people to your
      products too.</div></section>
    <section>
      Thumbnail: <img itemprop="image" src="thing.png"/>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I make a request using this example, it works.  But when I use the same markup on a page in my own site I get this error response:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "badRequest",
    "message": "Unable to fetch metadata."
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Unable to fetch metadata."
 }
}
```

It must have something to do with the url and not my structured markup.  The url looks like https://mysite/path/view.html and when I use the [google structured data testing tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets) the metadata is extracted. I tried to leave out the object url, and instead specify metadata in the post body like

```
'"object": {
            "kind": "plus#itemScope",
            "id": "id",
            "description": "description",
            ...
```

but this is not working.  I am using PHP and cURL to send the request.  I know that the php client library for the google api would be preferable but I'm using cURL in this situation.

Comment: Solved.  In case this helps anyone: This was a general server misunderstanding on my part.  If you are using https in your object url, google will not be able to access it if the certificate is self-signed.  At least I believe this was the problem because it works with http.